# Is it possible to play PSO online on GameCube?

Tags: nintendo-gamecube, phantasy-star-online

I assume the servers for this game were taken down long ago. Is there any other way of playing over the net with my friends?

Comment: Which version/platform? For Dreamcast, see [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/112726/30863). (Related: for Xbox, even for playing offline, see [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/113901/30863)).

Comment: Thanks, I've added that this is referring to the gamecube version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way to connect to easily connect to private servers using a hacked Wii to play the game using Devolution, a gamecube emulator that can emulate the broadband adapter.

Following the details from this [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UEByqyGMLh8) I was able to log into both the [Schtserv](http://www.schtserv.com/) that troylatroy referenced as well as the [l33tserv](http://www.l33tservpso.net/).

I recently hacked my friend's Wii and set this up for him so if there are any further questions feel free to message me.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few private servers that still exist(I think). I found this one, http://www.schtserv.com/, but the website hasn't been updated in a while.

Comment: I believe this private server is still operational.  I've found details on how to log into it using a hacked Wii.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the official game servers are offline, but you can still play on private servers with your GameCube.

For example, on

- [**Sylverant**](http://sylverant.net/) ([GameCube instruction](http://sylverant.net/connecting-to-sylverant/#psogc)) or
- [**Schtserv**](http://schtserv.com/) ([GameCube instruction](http://schtserv.com/connect-psogc.php)).

In the lobbies, you can chat with players on all platforms (Dreamcast/Windows), but playing is (currently) only possible with other GameCube users.